# Two Finger Scroll in Ubuntu 15.10 as VMware Guest

Tags: touchpad, vmware, multi-touch, synaptics

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 as a guest from Windows 8.1 with VMware. There is no option to enable/disable Two finger scroll in System settings. By default, two finger horizontal scroll is enabled but two finger vertical scroll isn't.
Touchpad - Synaptics SMbus (As shown by Windows Device Manager).
Tried Ubuntu Tweak to modify settings - No change.
Previously, I had Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS dual-boot which had this option in System Settings.
Output of xinput command -

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VMware VMware Virtual USB Mouse           id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```